# How to split a string into list of characters in PROLOG?

Tags: prolog, dcg

Currently, in my code, I have a list of words arranged as follows:

```
lexical_item --> [a,m].
lexical_item --> [e,s,t].
lexical_item --> [r,a,p,i,d].
...
```

That is, when I need to add a new word (eg. 'car'), I have to manually add it as [c,a,r]...

How can I have in my code something like the following:

```
lexical_item --> [am].
lexical_item --> [est].
lexical_item --> [rapid].
...
```

And, when i run my code, automatically transform 'rapid' in 'r,a,p,i,d', instead of having to previously add the word with all the letters divided by a comma?

Comment: I would suggest to use [tokenize_atom](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=tokenize_atom/2), but this would make the last part of your question irrelevant.

Comment: I don't know why you uses DCG in such case.
Can't you define directly without using DCG?

how about defining just like below ?
lexical_item(am).
lexical_item(est).
lexical_item(rapid).
lexical_item(car).

if you need DGG form compatibility,
try 
listing(lexical_item ).
on console and check the converted prolog code
and what to write it without using DCG

Comment: This is what [`term_expansion/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=term_expansion%2f2) is for.

Answer (score 1):

> automatically transform 'rapid' in 'r,a,p,i,d'

I'm not sure why all commenters failed to point out that what you want is `atom_chars/2`:

```
?- atom_chars(rapid, Chars).
Chars = [r, a, p, i, d].

?- atom_chars(Atom, [r, a, p, i, d]).
Atom = rapid.
```

The idea is to separate your database of words (represented as atoms) from the `lexical_item//0` DCG rule, and to do the conversion inside that:

```
word(am).
word(est).
word(rapid).

lexical_item -->
    { word(W),
      atom_chars(W, Chars) },
    list(Chars).

list([]) -->
    [].
list([X|Xs]) -->
    [X],
    list(Xs).
```

As written, the `lexical_item//0` rule can be used very generally, to recognize words, reject non-words, and to enumerate all the words in the database:

```
?- phrase(lexical_item, [r,a,p,i,d]).
true.

?- phrase(lexical_item, [s,o,m,e,t,h,i,n,g]).
false.

?- phrase(lexical_item, Item).
Item = [a, m] ;
Item = [e, s, t] ;
Item = [r, a, p, i, d].
```

This is great from a logical point of view, but operationally, it would be more efficient to have the goals in the rule in the exact opposite order.